# Glue 2 divs to top-right and bottom-left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery's resizable(). I want to be able to make a div stick on top-right corner and the other div to be bottom left corner at all times. I'm looking to make these 2 divs be as the resizable handles `ne` and `sw` would be positioned.

How do I make `$(".td")` and `$(".tl")`stick on top-right and bottom-left of `$(".nWrapper")` at all times?

html:

```
<div class="lWrapper">
    <div class="nWrapper">
        <div class="tWrapper">
            <div class="td"></div>
            <div class="tl"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.lWrapper{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.nWrapper{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.tWrapper{
    position: absolute;
}
.td{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    left: 0; /*want it left bottom*/
    bottom: 0;
}
.t1{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right; /*want it right top*/
    top: 0;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ze9go151/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the wrapping div (nWrapper) to have `position: relative` and the the smaller ones to have `position: absolute` and give to these two appropriate left/right/top/bottom values.

Check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/ze9go151/2/